# Fuzzy string matching in Golang

Tags: go

Is there any go module for doing fuzzy string matching ?. If i have an array of strings, i want to check whether a given string fuzzy matches with any of the elements in the array.

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: http://godoc.org/?q=fuzzy

Comment: Why on earth these 7 people closed this question? This is a valid question, from my perspective, and I am a SO user of many years.

Answer (score 7):

You are probably looking for a library which implements [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm.

This is also the algorithm used by [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) fuzzy searching.

See here a list of [Go packages](https://godoc.org/?q=Levenshtein).